# Is changing the surname important after getting married in France for applying spouse visa?

Tags: france

I need to apply spouse visa for France and and my all previous documents, birth certificate etc are named with Tania Raza so now I’ve changed my ID card with the martial status married and husband name is mentioned but I’ve not changed my name as it is in previous documents I’ve kept it the same both in the passport and ID card. So is it fine or do I have to change my surname on my husband’s name before applying for the visa? What is important according to France laws, terms and conditions.

Comment: If your name did not change, then your marriage certificate is not a "change of name" document. It is still a record of the marriage.

Answer (score 9):

Even though many (possibly most) women take their husband's name upon marriage:

- This is far from universal, and definitely not mandatory
- On all official paperwork (ID cards, passports), they keep their original name, with the addition "Epouse X", rather than actually change their name.

So no, there's absolutely no requirement for you to change your name when it comes to french law.